# A problem on realboxes: unexpected vertical space

Tags: boxes

I had sent an e-mail to Martin, and I have not received reply from him.

Compare the codes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{realboxes}
\begin{document}
The above line

\Parbox[t]{5cm}{Some text}
\end{document}
```

with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{realboxes}
\begin{document}
The above line

\Parbox[t]{5cm}{Some text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

you might find that the two lines are closer in the latter. What does make this problem? How do I eliminate the vertical space?

Comment: It's a math library problem. If you replace TikZ line with `\usepackage[pgfmath]{adjcalc}` you will get the same issue.

Comment: @percusse However, if I load `adjcalc` by `\usepackage[etex]{adjcalc}`, the difference still shows if `tikz` is also loaded.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I was just trying to understand how that happened indeed. I can't see any switch anywhere other than maybe buried in `collectbox` yet. I think it is a pgfmath v3.00 vs v2.10 issue

Comment: It is not the math, it is the color. `\usepackage{color}` triggers the same space. Probably the same problem that leads to space when you use `\color` in p-columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`realboxes` doesn't prevent the use of color whatsits at the start of the internally saved box. This isn't a complete fix but it works OK here. `tikz` is only related as it includes `color`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{realboxes}
\makeatletter
\let\collectbox@setgroup\begingroup
\makeatletter
\begin{document}


The above line

\Parbox[t]{5cm}{

Some text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Anyway, thanks. After waiting few days I've decided to take your answer although it is not a general fix.